# Не удаётся спарсить скрытое значение в коде

Tags: python, bs4

Для парсинга использую bs4.
В скрине, красным отмечен код, который появляется только при наведении мыши.
Не удаётся спарсить значение = 16

*Буду благодарен, если поможете и подскажете, что делаю не так!*

**Мой код:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://csgofastx.com/game/x50'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'x50-history-popover__desc', 'data-bind': 'text:s'})
convert = result[0].text
print(result)
```

[image: Код]

Comment: Используйте селенимум

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать @СергейШ